# PHP , MYSQL , HTML , JQUERy animated forms with validating

Tags: jquery, html, css, mysql, forms

i'm tryin to make a old bnet Warcraft 3 login and bnet ui on my wamp server. The exact problem is whenever i try to execute my jquery func it just do a little "move" in the direciton i want to move my html code is

```
<div style="height:100%;width:50%;" class='left'>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input class='username' type='text' name='username'><br>
 <input  class='pw' type='password' name='password'><br>
 <input  class='submit' type='submit' id='login_btn' name='submit'>
</form>
</div>
<div style="height:100%;width:50%;" class='right'>
    </div>
```

my CSS is :

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   overflow:hidden;

  }
.left {


background: url(ui/left.png);
position:absolute;
background-position: center left;
background-size:cover;

}

.right {

background: url(ui/right.png);
background-position: center right;
position:absolute;
background-size:cover;
right:0px;


}

input {

outline:none;

  }

  .username {

border:none;
width:565px;
height:69px;
background: url(ui/textbox.png);
margin-top:300px;
margin-left:120px;
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
color:white;

  }
    .pw{

border:none;
width:565px;
height:69px;
background: url(ui/textbox.png);
margin-top:60px;
margin-left:120px;
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;

  }

      .submit{

border:none;
width:446px;
height:85px;
background: url(ui/button.png);
margin-top:60px;
margin-left:210px;
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
color:white;

  }
```

PHP :

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM uzivatele WHERE login = '$myusername' and heslo = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
             echo "    $('.left').animate({left: '250px'});";
      }else {
      }
   }
?>
```

and i want to be the animation like this :

[anim.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMqRD.gif)

The thing is everytime i try to execute the jquery animation the class left and class right barely moves about 1-3px and then back like in blink of an eye. Even if mixin server & client sided languages like is is "impossible" is there any other solution i could use for this?

Comment: Where is your jQuery?

Comment: $("form").submit(function(){
        $(".left").animate({left: '-42%'},3000);
        $(".right").animate({right: '-42%'},3000);

});
};

Comment: damn i forgot , lol

Comment: Shouldn't the right be animated `42%`, not `-42%`?

Comment: yes , it should , but somehow on pure html , css & jquery it worked , so i let it how it is, but afterwards i've added some php come it just did this.